# How to make Juju connect to Openstack VM using ProxyCommand / ssh config?

Tags: ssh, juju, proxy, openstack

My Openstack VMs in my setup can be only access using a gateway machine. I always need to use a ProxyCommand to connect to them.

Now I work with juju and, after setting up metadata and tools, I run juju bootstrap. Everything works fine, but the juju is not able to connect to the newly started VM. Juju assumes that the connection is direct.

How can I make juju use ssh_config or predefine ProxyCommand for all VMs for a given environment?

Answer (score 2):

My current solution is: find out the IP schema for internal IPs (in my case: 10.115.x.x) and create corresponding rule in the ssh config:

```
Host 10.115.*
    ProxyCommand ssh forward@my_gateway_machine nc -q0 %h %p
```